# Does %w[].each do work in a rails controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sinatra

I'm trying to follow along this tutorial from Twilio -->http://www.twilio.com/docs/howto/search-and-buy

But, it being written in Sinatra, I'm getting confused trying to convert it to rails.

I want to convert this, into two actions, :create, and :show, with respective view

```
filespost '/search-numbers' do
  account_sid = 'ACXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'
  auth_token = 'YYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYY'

  client = Twilio::REST::Client.new(account_sid, auth_token)

  search_params = {}
  %w[in_postal_code near_number contains].each do |p|
    search_params[p] = params[p] unless params[p].nil? || params[p].empty?
  end

  begin
    local_numbers = client.account.available_phone_numbers.get('US').local
    numbers = local_numbers.list(search_params)

    unless numbers.empty?
      out = '<html><head><title>Choose a number</title></head><body><h3>Choose a number</h3>'
      numbers.each do |number|
        out << "<form method='POST' action='/buy-number'>"
        out << "<label>#{number.friendly_name}</label>"
        out << "<input type='hidden' name='PhoneNumber' value='#{number.phone_number}' />"
        out << "<input type='submit' value='BUY' /></form>"
      end
      out << '</body></html>'
    else
      '<b>Sorry!</b> Twilio doesn\'t have any numbers available that match those constraints.'
    end
  rescue StandardError => e
    '<b>Sorry!</b> ' + e.message + '.'
  end
```

end

So, my thinking is to create a find_numbers controller, with new, create, and show. The new is just a form with no ties to a database. The Create action should than make an array of numbers, and the show action should show them.

I get confused here `First Confusion is this, which I guess goes into the create action -- >

```
  search_params = {}
  %w[in_postal_code near_number contains].each do |p|
    search_params[p] = params[p] unless params[p].nil? || params[p].empty?
  end
```

`

I'm not sure if this works in a rails controller.

The rest, I would guess would go into the show action, but the question here would be, how would the show action be able to call the search_params?

I've been tweaking for hours now, any guidance would be greatly appreciated!!!

---

**UPDATE**

After Learning more about how forms work in rails, I tried moving this code over to a new controller "find_numbers", with a new action, create action, and show action. Show show gives the error :

```
NoMethodError in Find_numbers#create

Showing C:/Sites/dct/app/views/find_numbers/show.html.erb where line #1 raised:

undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass
```

I'm thinking it's because the numbers instance variable is nil, because something before it did not work.

Here's my controller :

class FindNumbersController < ApplicationController

```
def new
    @user = current_user
end

def create
    @user = current_user
    render 'find_numbers/show'
end

def show
    @user = current_user
    client = Twilio::REST::Client.new(@user.twilio_account_sid, @user.twilio_auth_token)

    search_params = {}
    %w(in_postal_code near_number contains).each do |p|
      search_params[p] = params[p] unless params[p].blank?
    end

    local_numbers = client.account.available_phone_numbers.get('US').local
    @numbers = local_numbers.list(search_params)    


end
```

end

## Note what I do know is that the current_user variable works. I think sometime after search_params it goes haywire

My show view

```
<%= number.friendly_name %>
<%= number.phone_number %>
```

Comment: `unless params[p].nil? || params[p].empty?` = `unless params[p].blank?`

Comment: Hmm I'm not sure what you mean, Would really appreciate an explanation  on what to change, and why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Rails, this should work:

```
search_params = {}
%w(in_postal_code near_number contains).each do |p|
  search_params[p] = params[p] unless params[p].blank?
end
```

if not.... what errors are you getting?

Comment: Hi Pavling, thanks for the reply. I tried implementing that, but I get this error :

NoMethodError in Find_numbers#create

Showing C:/Sites/dentist/app/views/find_numbers/show.html.erb where line #1 raised:

undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass

I updated the post above to reflect how the new controller, and view looks like

Comment: Can you post a little more of the error, as line 1 of your view doesn't seem to use .each

Comment: Hi Pavling, 

I had multiple misconceptions here that got cleared up. Not only did I not have the do.each, but I was also creating the @numbers instance in the wrong action. You can take a look at the full solution here. 

Thanks for clarifying on this.